# invalidate NSTimer inside dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nstimer

I am creating a game, and inside the game I need to get a time counter.

I works great but when I scroll the map it stops and then when I finish scrolling it start again. I fix this with dispatch_async. Here is the code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self  selector:@selector(timeNext) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; 
            });
```

Timer:

```
__block NSTimer *timer;
```

But if the app goes to the background I need to stop this times (and when it get active it starts again).

With this way I can scroll the map and the timer works well I try:

```
- (void)timeNext {
    [timer invalidate];
    }
```

and didin't work. Anyone knows how to stop it? or any other idea to accomplish this task?

Comment: You've added a timer into the run-loop of random thread, and you suddenly want to just invalidate it?  You need a safer threading mechanism, not a better invalidation method.

Comment: And how can I make this,  I also try perfmSelector:OnThread and create a new thread and doesn't work

Comment: You shouldn't be adding that timer to a run loop -- it's not necessary with that method. That method schedules the timer on a run loop for you , and starts it immediately.

Comment: just check  if([timer isValid]) [timer invalidate];

Comment: @sugan.s I am doing that and the timer won't stop it just continue working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create your timer on a global queue's thread and then start a run loop on that thread.

Just create your timer on the main thread (main run loop), and add it to the tracking run loop mode.  A timer can be added to multiple run loop modes.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self  selector:@selector(timeNext) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Since scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: already schedules the timer on the current run loop in default mode, will this cause the timer to run in two different modes?

Comment: No.  It will cause the timer to run in the main run loop (assuming it's set up on the main thread), in either of two different run loop modes.  If you don't know about run loop modes, [read this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW12).

Comment: Hi rob, I put your code but when I move the map it doesn't work the timer. And I need to scroll the map minimum one time so the timer starts - Edit: If I change UITrackingRunLoopMode to NSDefaultRunLoopMode it work without scrolling the map

Comment: It sounds like you are creating your timer using `timerWithTimeInterval:...` (as Oladya suggested), rather than `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:` (as I suggested).  If you create it with `timerWithTimeInterval:`, you need to use `addTimer:forMode:` twice, once for each run loop mode.

Comment: I didn't realize that scrolling would cause the timer not to fire, and that adding it to the UITrackingRunLoopMode also would fix that. Thanks for the link, I think I understand what's going on with the run loops now.

Comment: @robmayoff I didn't see that difference, And it works but When I scroll the timer stops :S Edit: My code: timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timeNext) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
            [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer2 forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];

Comment: @Ernesto, did you try currentRunLoop rather then mainRunLoop as Rob suggested?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I test it both ways, and when I drag the screen the timer stop "[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer2 forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];"

Comment: will this cause the timer to run in two different modes? Heaven knows what it does. I don't care. Just don't do this!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UIScrollView to scroll via your game world, timer will be paused while scroll is tracking touches - you need to setup timer to use it with different mode - `UITrackingRunLoopMode`, e.g.

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
```

instead of

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

This will allow your timer to fire events while controls such as scroll is tracking user's touches.

[EDIT]

You create timer e.g. via

```
+ (NSTimer *)timerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti target:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```

then add this timer to runloop (basically, you should add it to your app main runloop):

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1./60. target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Hi, You said that I put that inside the run loop or just the Timer and that function? Because I just do it and it works fine (my code, also works fine) but when I want to stop the timer. I can't. And yes my world map it's a UIScrollView

Comment: @Ernesto You need to set up your timer on the main thread, **and** do what Oladya says.  Don't dispatch to a global queue to run the timer.

Comment: He needs to add the timer to the default run loop mode **and** the tracking run loop mode.

Comment: Hi Oladya, It works but weird, because it doesn't start the loop until I scroll the map, and when I'am scrolling the map the counter works fine, but when I left it start "jumping" in 5 per 5 (it executes 1 time per second)

Comment: If I change UITrackingRunLoopMode to NSDefaultRunLoopMode it work without scrolling the map

Comment: Also, you can check out WWDC 2012 video of session 223 - here they use openGL and uiscrollviews and solving same issues as you have with timers

Comment: @OladyaKane ok will check it out

Answer (score 0):

I use `NSRunLoopCommonModes` instead of `UITrackingRunLoopMode`, everythings looks fine. The main thread ui operation will not block `tick` function anymore.

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1./60. target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```